# Only a certain user can execute this program

Tags: c

I don't seem to have found any questions regarding this so here we go.

I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/jPW_0BFxAYU?t=2203) (in the video the program gets executed by the wrong user and the program prints out that the wrong user executed this program and halts further execution) when I saw this program called doCom, which checks whether the user executing the program is a certain user. My questions would be:

- Is this a secure practice? In the case being there were no vulns like there are now no known ones.
- How do I program something like this in a compilable language like C? If you can't into C any compilable language should do.

Comment: No. It is not secure. I edit your python code, put my user name into it and presto: I can execute it. I exchange the call to your doCom program with my own program that allows me execution. Security is a big complex topic - not good answerable here unless you have a very specific problem and supply your [mre] with it - currently the question is _too broad_.

Comment: @PatrickArtner ok let's scratch the Python idea then. What if the Linux system is in lockdown and only certain commands are configured to be runnable, binary is read-only, is it safe then? I'm talking about a perfect environment.

Comment: No. Essentially you would set the chmods of your executionable files to 700 so only the user can execute them and you let the login stuff be handled by the OS. If the user account is compromised, you are toast though.

Comment: @PatrickArtner ok abrupt change of question then: How do I using permissions and programming setup a custom message that the user can't execute this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the answer is that if you properly secure your system, that the program CAN validate users and decide what the user can/can not do, potentially not allowing the user to do nothing.

Recall that every web application is performing authorization based on the userid. Similarly many Unix tools will permit only subset of users to use them - based on explicit user list, or attributes of the users (group membership, etc). Common example are `sudo` (via /etc/sudoers), crontab (/etc/cron.allow), etc.

**Want to emphasize that the system must be properly secured.**

Going back into your question - implementing permission with python/C.

- it's usually very very hard to protect pure scripting based solution against attack from local users. In those situation, users can usually copy the whole program tree, and make modification to disable permission check. This approach is consider unsafe. Same apply to Java (and other VM based solution), where the code can be copied, disassembled, and modified.
- Protecting binary programs (compiled code) - C, C++, fortran, - from local users - is possible by leveraging execute permission (setting the permission to execute only, no read, no write). This approach is used for many utilities (`sudo`, `crontab`, ...). This is usually combined with `setuid` prevent the local user from reading data files that are part of the security setup.
- Alternative approach, which can be used with scripting and binary programs is to perform the critical operation via a daemon (a.k.a service), running as a different user (usually started at startup). In those cases, the scripting part of the solution acts as a "front-end" to a service that will authorize actions before performing them.

Update 1: Skeleton for binary programs

The following program will disclose the "Secret" only to user 'foo' or to users who are member of the 'foo' group (either as primary group, or as supplemental group). See important note below.

Build with `cc -c check.c ; chmod 111 a.out`

You can either add group/user foo to your system, or modify the code to match you own setting. Running either show the secret, or show 'unauthorized' depending on the user setting. Other users should not be able to read a.out directly to decode the password.

```
// check.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool valid(void) ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if ( !valid() ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unathorized\n") ;
        } ;
        printf("Secret!") ;
}

static bool valid(void)
{
        struct passwd *the_user = getpwuid(getuid()) ;
        if ( the_user && !strcmp(the_user->pw_name, "foo")) return true ;

                // Check if user is member of 'foo' group
        struct group *the_group = getgrnam("foo") ;
        if ( the_group ) {
                if ( the_user && the_group && the_user->pw_gid == the_group->gr_gid ) return true ;

                // supplementary group IDs

                int group_count = getgroups(0, NULL) ;
                int groups[group_count] ;
                getgroups(group_count, groups) ;
                for (int i=0 ; i<group_count ; i++) {
                        if ( groups[i] == the_group->gr_gid ) return true ;
                } ;
        } ;
        return false ;
}
```

Disclaimer: This is baseline protection - **for demonstration and learning purpose only**. Solution does not provide ANY protection against super users, users who can read the whole disk, and other users with special admin power. For simple use case, consider using existing alternatives (ACL, sudo, ...). Using this framework make it possible to built custom security rules into a program.

Comment: Brilliant. Can you add some example code/pseudocode for checking the user id/name? Or at least the methodology how I could achieve it.

Comment: @SirMuffington posted baseline for binary programs, should be a reasonable starting point to protect access against local users.

Answer (score 1):

I did not watch your video.  Inasmuch as we expect SO questions to be self-contained, I take the question to be generally about programs that check the user before running.

> - Is this a secure practice? In the case being there were no vulns like there are now no known ones.

It is as secure as the user account involved and the script itself.  If that account is compromised then the approach provides no security at all.  If the binary can be modified by someone other than the designated user then likewise.

> - How do I program something like this in C/Python3? If you can't into C/Python any compilable language should do.

It would be wasteful to program this when better facilities are already built in to substantially all operating systems that distinguish between different users in the first place.  In particular, Windows and all Unix variants (including Linux and macOS) provide mechanisms by which access to a program / script can be restricted to one or more specific users by setting properties of the file wherein it resides.

The actual "How to?" question posed is too broad for SO.

Comment: Ok, maybe then the program could enchance the integrated permissions systems in that way? The program would be compiled and secured (made read-only) to prevent manipulation.

Comment: @SirMuffington, if the OS prevents any user other than the designated one from executing the program then the program itself verifying that the OS has in fact done so adds little security.  It is more difficult to manage, too.  I cannot imagine why anyone would devote effort to such an endeavor.